# How do you stop google drive insisting on 700/600 permissions?

Tags: google-drive-api

This completely destroys any hope of using google drive for shared assets when developing.
System level services such as apache do not run as the logged in user.

Permissions stick until someone else makes an edit and the updates are then synced.

Google drive, changes the permissions of directories and  files to 700 and 600 respectively.
This results in 503 forbidden requests in Apache or any other process not running as the logged in user.

Is there anyway to get Google Drive to stop destroying my permissions?
Maybe by respecting my umask, or some option to configure it.

755 for directories and 644 for files would be much more appropriate.

Comment: Since Google Drive doesn't have an official Linux client at this point, what client are you using? It seems unlikely this is a Google Drive SDK issue, but an issue with whatever client you are using?

Comment: Ahh yeh sorry, I'm using the Mac Client.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately this a product issue, and your post on the [Drive Help Forum](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/drive/fUuPbRZsIb0) is the correct way to raise this concern.

Comment: Thanks for your time, I though so too. Unfortunately the Google Drive forums are a waste of time. I'll go back to using Dropbox.

Comment: Posted https://support.google.com/drive/thread/262350121/on-a-mac-client-stat-x-plaintextfile-txt-reports-mode-0600-with-no-access-for-group-members today, nearly 10 years later. Same problem exists today, so it must not be a problem... ;-)